# Почему компилятор считает, что переменная уже была объявлена

Tags: c#, .net, область-видимости

Вот код (этот квиксорт я пока что не доделал):

```
    private static void QuickSort(int[] array, int start, int end)
    {
        if (start == end)
            return;

        int pivot = start;
        int left = start, right = start + 1;

        for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; ++i)
        {
            if (array[i] <= pivot)
            {
                int temp = array[right];
                array[right] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                ++left;
                ++right;
            }
        }
        int temp;

        QuickSort(array, start, left);
        QuickSort(array, right, end);
    }
```

Компилятор утверждает, что переменная temp не может быть объявлена после цикла фор, ибо там же она уже и объявлена. Но ведь в цикле фор область видимости совсем иная? И после этого цикла переменная temp, если она там была, исчезает. 
Так почему же я не могу объявить второй раз переменную temp, но уже, казалось бы, в другой области видимости?

Comment: С зоной видимости вы правы, но тут просто сам компилятор с деббагером так устроен, что нельзя в одной процедуре сделать две локальные переменные с одним именем, видимо, потому что массив локальных переменных один на всю функцию.

Comment: "... так как это имя используется во включающей локальной области для определения локальной переменной или параметра"

Comment: [Compiler Error CS0136](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136)

Comment: Прийдётся вам дать другое имя переменной. Из CS0136 ccылки нарушение не вижу... Да, у меня такое же самое поведение.

Comment: @nick_n_a, как ж не видишь? там же выдержка из спецификации даж

Comment: Я тоже не вижу. Там другой пример.

Comment: Я уже смотрел эту ссылку. Там пример того, что объявляется переменная i над скобками фигурными, и в фигурных скобках снова объявляется i. Что логично является ошибкой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Областью видимости (Scope) локальной переменной](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/statements.md#local-variable-declarations) в C# является весь блок, а не только часть от объявления до конца блока.

> The scope of a local variable declared in a local_variable_declaration is the block in which the declaration occurs.

При этом к переменной нельзя обращаться до той текстовой позиции, в которой она объявлена:

> It is an error to refer to a local variable in a textual position that precedes the local_variable_declarator of the local variable. Within the scope of a local variable, it is a compile-time error to declare another local variable or constant with the same name.

Несмотря на то, что в вашем примере нет точки, в которой вы можете обратиться одновременно к двум переменным temp, области их видимости пересекаются, и вы получаете ошибку компиляции.

Answer (score 5):

Областью видимости переменной temp являются те фигурные скобки в которых она объявлена. Даже в строках до ее объявления она считается видимой, хоть ее и нельзя использовать.

Это легко увидеть на примере (обратите внимание на различие в текстах ошибок):

```
// error CS0841: Cannot use local variable 'foo' before it is declared
Console.WriteLine(foo);

// error CS0103: The name 'bar' does not exist in the current context
Console.WriteLine(bar);

string foo;
```